# Creating index in mongo 3

Tags: mongodb

I want to create an index so that my DB does not allow me to insert documents whose value for the key `lema` is already present in some document of the DB. I did this:

```
db.version()
3.0.14
> db.rae.ensureIndex({"lema":1, unique: true})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "note" : "all indexes already exist",
    "ok" : 1
}
> db.rae.insert({"lema":"a"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.rae.insert({"lema":"a"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.rae.insert({"lema":"a"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.rae.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591a0ce372329f3162a314cc"), "lema" : "a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591a0ce472329f3162a314cd"), "lema" : "a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591a0ce572329f3162a314ce"), "lema" : "a" }
```

Clearly the DB is letting me insert documents whose values of `lema` are all `a`. How can I fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the output of `db.rae.getIndexes()`? The message "all indexes already exist" suggests that you already have a non-unique index on `lema:1`. In that case, you'd need to remove any duplicate values, drop the existing `lema:1` index, and then create the unique index.

Comment: @Stennie, I droped the whole collection and created it again. This is the result: `> db.rae.getIndexes()
[
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "tweets.rae"
 }
]
`

Comment: @Stennie Should I proceed o create the index as I did?

Comment: Your syntax isn't quite right (missing braces for the unique option) and you should also use `createIndex` instead of the deprecated `ensureIndex`. Try: `db.rae.createIndex({"lema":1}, { unique: true})`.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks, can you post this as an answer so that the question does not remain unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

From Stennie's comment:

I should use `createIndex` instead of `ensureIndex`. Also I had a mistake, I should use `db.rae.createIndex({"lema":1}, { unique: true})`.